# Turn off vim's `filetype indent` for a specific filetype

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

In my `.vimrc` I have

```
filetype indent on
```

Now, the way it attempts to auto-indent `yaml` files is very confusing for me, so I want to turn `filetype indent` off, but only for `yaml` files, not for other files.

How do I tell it so in my `.vimrc`?

Answer (score 6):

@maiki's answer provides the right solution; if you need to keep this in `~/.vimrc`, the following is equivalent:

```
autocmd FileType yaml let b:did_indent = 1
```

If this doesn't work, you can also try to clear the indent method afterwards:

```
autocmd FileType yaml setlocal indentexpr=
```

I'd still suggest you look into changing your setup so that more than your `.vimrc` can be easily synced. Consider that you may want to use plugins or other configurations (like `~/.gitconfig`) in the future. There exist many approaches for syncing user configuration across systems; many users have them in a central (Git) repository and use symlinks to install.

Comment: This didn't work for me; however, `setlocal indentexpr=` instead of `let b:did_indent = 1` worked.

Comment: Did you type that in, or actually put in .vimrc? It's important that this autocmd is defined first. Well, anyway, you've found a solution! I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Same here, putting `let b:did_indent = 1` in `~/.vimrc` did not work. I tried putting it before and after `filetype plugin indent on`, neither worked. However, `autocmd FileType yaml setlocal indentexpr=` did work. It must be added after `filetype plugin indent on`.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick

```
echo 'let b:did_indent = 1' > ~/.vim/indent/yaml.vim
```

[source](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting)

Comment: I don't know if this works, but it would require me to do this on all my machines, and remember to do it each time I have a new machine. No good. It should be enough to merely copy my `.vimrc`.